# How to use a parent query value in select statement of subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an aggregate query and a subquery and I want to use one of the values from the 'parent' query in a formula in the select statement for the subquery ...

Something like this, where I want to access that 'The_Total' alias in the subquery  ...

```
SELECT some_field, COUNT () AS The_Total,
    (SELECT The_Total / 100 FROM Some_Table) AS The_Total_Div_100
FROM Some_Table
GROUP BY some_field
```

Would produce a result like this ...

```
some_field | The_Total | The_Total_div_100
------------------------------------------
Fred       |   100     |        1
Mary       |   200     |        2
Bob        |   300     |        3
```

The query I have is much more complicated than that with joins and where clauses etc but it is this ability to reference a parent query value in a subquery select formula that has me stuck.  I have tried "SELECT (The_Total)" instead of just The_Total etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "access" aliases directly in the  `select` clause or the `where` clause.

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE (or SELECT) clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

You need to write up that formula again.

```
SELECT some_field, 
       COUNT () AS Total,
       COUNT () * 100 / (select count(*) from Some_Table) AS Total_percentage
FROM Some_Table
GROUP BY some_field
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not going to work.  I know I could produce that table above like this but it has to work in a subquery ...

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to access aliases in a SELECT clause from within the same SELECT clause.

However, it is possible to move the entire query with the alias into a subquery:

```
SELECT some_field,
       The_Total,
       (SELECT The_Total / COUNT(*)
        FROM Some_Table
       ) AS fraction_of_The_Total
FROM (SELECT some_field,
             COUNT(*) AS The_Total
      FROM Some_Table
      GROUP BY some_field)
```

Comment: I really need the value in the subquery, not the other way around.  Because I determine a 'count' in the subquery and then I want to calculate what proportion of the parent query count that is ...

Comment: This is a different kind of subquery. Anyway, the subquery in the question *does not make sense* because it does not access its own instance of `Some_Table`; show what you actually want to calculate.